# Не работает скрипт

Tags: jquery

Добрый день.
Только изучаю jQuery, не могу понять. почему у меня не срабатывает такой вот простой скрипт

```
<script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
        function displayDimention() {
            $(".display").height(20).html(
                $(".testSubject").width()+'x'+$(".testSubject").height()
        );

        };
        });
    </script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/GF5GX/1/
Подскажите, в чем у меня ошибка?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У вас функция `displayDimention()` нигде не вызывается.

Comment: @lampa, а почему скрипт не срабатывает даже если убрать из него функцию http://jsfiddle.net/GF5GX/2/ ?

Comment: @mironny потому что синтаксическая ошибка в коде :) Там же есть кнопочка "JSHint". У вас пропущена закрывающая скобка.

Comment: Всё, понятно, большое спасибо!